# Showing information after replacement

Tags: powershell

I use below code to change strings in files:

```
Set-Location -Path C:\Users\Documents\corporate
foreach ($file in get-ChildItem *.rdl)
{
     $_.Replace("Protection", "Converters")  | Set-Content $file
     $_.Replace("Drives", "Automation")  | Set-Content $file
     $_.Replace("MACHINES", "Generators")  | Set-Content $file

    
     $file.name
}
```

I want to add information what has changed in individual files.

For example:

> file 1 Protection
>
> file 3 Protection, MACHINES

Comment: Hi, what does `$con` refer to, in your code ?

Comment: It refer to path. Now is redundant but earlier it's equal Get-Content .\Documents.rdl

Comment: If it is redundant, why is it still in the script? Please make the code readable and include all relevant variables

Comment: For one thing there's no current object (`$_`) in a `foreach` loop. Also, "add information" ... *where*?

Comment: Aside from the above comments, `Set-Content $file` is going to overwrite `$file` for each line inside the `foreach` loop. I would recommend against guesswork when trying to program things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way ...

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Documents\corporate" -Filter "*.rdl" | ForEach-Object { 
    $Local:CurrentFileFullName = $_.FullName
    ((Get-Content -Path $CurrentFileFullName ) -replace "Protection", "Converters" -replace "Drives", "Automation" -replace "MACHINES", "Generators" | Set-Content $CurrentFileFullName -Force)
}
```